Error: (0 , h.requestMetadata) is not a function
I was on the 3rd step of the Ubuntu tutorial, this Error code always appears, no matter the version. i was using "balenaEtcher" like the tutorial said. Any idea what it means? my latest try was with Ubuntu 24.04 for desktops. and i was trying it on a Windows 10 laptop.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! As far as I know, there isn't the Ubuntu tutorial, so it's hard to tell what you're talking about ;) Please edit your question with further information, for example a link to the tutorial, what exactly step 3 is, what you're doing exactly, what you expect to happen etc. This should help us with helping you.

The error message and the information that we're talking about Balena Etcher happened to be enough to find out that this seems to be a known bug in the newest version or versions of Balena Etcher. You may want to try a version that's a little older. In the issue comments I've linked above, Balena Etcher 1.18.11 is mentioned as working, but you may need to try which version works for you.

1.18.11 fails to install on 24.04 due to unmet dependencies.

I had the same error.
The fist step I took was to run Balena as Admin (windows) and would get the same problem.
FYI, I was flashing from a URL.
I then uninstall Etcher/Reinstalled and had the same error. However, now if I run the program as Admin I get it to flash (From URL to SD card).
This error seem to have to do with the current update, as mentionned by Henning Kockerbeck.
